# Entity Framework: No database connection has been configured for this model

Tags: c#, wpf

I was trying to update the return values of a stored procedure but for some reason *Entity Framework* tells me there is no connection for this model (cfr. first screenshot). Due to this problem I am unable to update the function nor the complex type.

[image: Function import menu]

Whenever I click the button *Update Model from Database...* I am prompted with the *Update Wizard*.

[image: Choose data connection menu]

This is what the connection string looks like in the app.config file.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WeighingEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.Weighing.WeighingModel.csdl|res://*/Model.Weighing.WeighingModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.Weighing.WeighingModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=sql2016;Initial Catalog=db2;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

This is a **WPF** application, I am using **EntityFramewrok 6.2.0** and the project is using the **.NET Framework 4.5** and my IDE is **Visual Studio 2017**. This was working previously. The database is working properly. I tried to add the data connection again using the *Update Wizard*. I did delete and recreate the *.edmx*. I also tried to delete the connection string in the file and then use the *Update Wizard* in order to recreate it.

None of my attemps did change anything I am still getting the message:

> *No database connection has been configured for this model.*

How can I get EF6 to work again?

Comment: It happened to me few times and I realized that Visual Studio is Caching the connection strings on startup. So restarting Visual Studio (reopening the project) helped me

Comment: I tried restarting visual studio but EF6 is still giving me the same error message

Comment: Ok, I tried that and I didn't see ConnectionString until I built the project and then restarted the Visual Studio. The update designer takes value from project output directory so when the project is not built yet, it leaves the ConnectionString property empty

Comment: The easy way to see all stored ConnectionStrings is using ServerExplrorer window. There you can manage stored EF model connection strings

Comment: In the ServerExplorer, I can se the connection and that the connection state is *Open* but the error persists !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a workaround but it does not solve the underlying issue:

> - Delete the *Stored Procedure*, the *Function Import* and the *Complex Type* in the **.edmx** file
> - Use the *UpdateWizard* to reimport the StoredProcedure

Answer (score 1):

Well I just got punished by this, so here's the solution.

It is an undocumented magic string match... great.

In the EDMX editor properties, there is a setting titled *Entity Container Name*
[image: Entity Container Name property screenshot]

This has to match the connection string name in App.config
[image: App config file screenshot]